# Postgres connection failure

Tags: ubuntu, sqlalchemy, port, postgresql-9.3

I'm using EC2 and trying to set up a port for postgres.  It's online, and I've changed my configuration files to allow access from ip address (and list_address = '*'). It still won't let me connect using sqlalchemy. I keep getting

```
Is the server running on host "172.31.x.XXx" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I've tried running npmap from my local ip and I'm getting the following

```
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 206.25 seconds
```

I'm new to this, so I might be missing something obvious, but any help is appreciated. I'm on a Mac btw

Answer (score 0):

There is also one file (pg_hba.conf) where changes require to accept request from any IP,

You can consider following link for complete understanding,

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-install-PostgreSQL-on-AWS-EC2-and-how-can-I-access-that